# Difference between hostname -i and ip addr show

Tags: linux, networking

What is the difference between the ip address of `hostname -i`, and the output of `ip addr`??, and what ip address of `hostname -i` is used for?

Answer (score 1):

As per `man hostname`

> ```
> -i, --ip-address
>           Display the network address(es) of the host name. Note that this
>           works only if the host name can be resolved.  Avoid  using  this
>           option; use hostname --all-ip-addresses instead.
> ```

This takes the hostname, performs a DNS lookup of that hostname, and displays the corresponding address.

`ip addr` will give you a full list of all interface, all IPs, aliases (if any), along with mac, state and so on.